# Finding the lexicographically largest rotations in the string

Tags: c++, string, lexicographic

I need to find the Lexicographically largest string out of the given input string.
So if the input is

```
enjoy
```

the o/p should be

```
yenjo
```

The code i tried was....

```
int n;
cout<<"Enter the number of strings";
cin>>n;
int len[n];
char str[n][1000];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>str[i];
    len[i]=strlen(str[i]);
}
int num,pos[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    pos[i]=0;
    num=int(str[i][0]);
    for(int j=1;j<len[i];j++)
    {
       if(int(str[i][j])>num)
        {
           num=int(str[i][j]);
           pos[i]=j;
       }   
    }    
}
int i,j,k;
char temp[1];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<pos[i];j++)
        {
        temp[0]=str[i][0];
        for(k=0;k<len[i];k++)
         {
            str[i][k]=str[i][k+1];
        }
        strcat(str[i],temp);
        str[i][len[i]]='\0';
    }
    cout<<str[i]<<"\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

But this code only ckecks for the largest number and not for the number present next to it and hence fails for the i/p

```
blowhowler
```

The o/p should be `wlerblowho` but i get the o/p as `whowlerblo`.

 How can i keep track of each element that preceeds the largest character so as to get the correct output?

Comment: Do you need to read all the lines into memory before processing any of them?  Wouldn't it be easier to repeat: read one line; process one line; print result?  It certainly would use less memory, and it would avoid the need to say how many lines will be entered up front.  You should be error checking the input operations.  You're using VLAs which are a GNU extension to C++ (though they're part of C99 and C11).

Comment: @codefreak, for enjoy the o/p should be yonje right?

Comment: it will be yenjo after rotating the string 5 times

Comment: @Rajesh: "yonje" is not a rotation of "enjoy", although it is a permutation.

Comment: okay got it, missed the rotation part.

Answer (score 3):

For good performance on the average case (actually, O(N)), but still O^2 on the worst (and always correct), you can keep track of possibilities, and keep eliminating them as you go. Basically something like this.

```
struct PermSum
{
  int sum;
  int perm;
}

LinkedList<PermSum> L;

for(int i = 0; i != input.size(); ++i) L.append(PermSum{0,i});

int depth = 0;
int max = 0;
const int length = input.size()
while(L.size() > 1 && depth < length)
{
  for(l in L)
  {
    l.sum += input[(l.perm + depth) % length]
    if (l.sum > max) max = l.sum
  }

  for(l in L)
  {
    if (l.sum < max) L.delete(l)
  }
  depth ++;
}

if (L.size() == 1)
  return L.front().perm
else
  return -1
```

I got a bit lazy in some parts with the c++ code but I'm sure you can figure out for l in L. The key line is the first for loop. The idea is that its adding the lexicographical value at the depth-th letter of the l.perm-th permutation. In this way, it updates all the possibilities, while simultaneously keeping track of the level of the best possibility. You then do a second pass to delete any possibility falling short of the best. It's worth noting that the way I coded this up, it probably uses the reverse of the standard convention for circular permutations. That is, the perm field in my program represents how many spots LEFT you circular shift, whereas usually positive numbers are circular shifting right. You can fix this with a minus sign somewhere.

As for the running time analysis, it's basically the same argument as Quickselect. Each while loop iteration takes time proportional to the length of L. The first iteration, L will always have length = N (where N is the length of the string, the same as the variable length in the code). The next round, we typically only expect 1/26 of the data to get through, the round after that 1/26 again... so we have N(1 + 1/26 + 2/26^2...) which is O(N).

Comment: Note that while this is algorithmically optimal, you can almost certainly get better real life performance by intelligently replacing the linked list by a std::vector (this is true because the order doesn't matter, so when you delete from the middle you can simply swap the last element in ).

Also, notice how each round we expect to do 1/26 the work of the previous. This is very dramatic compared to Quickselect. This means the first round is almost all of the work; as such its probably worth coding the first round specially (probably speed things up, and reduce max storage by a factor of 26).

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved in O(n log n) time by appending the string to itself first and build the suffix array out of it. Find the corresponding entry and there your wanted result. Implementation left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You can just:
1. generate rotations 
2. put all rotations in map<>
3. find last element of the map.
Here is the implementation in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str;int len,i=0,j=0,k=0;char temp;
    cin>>str;
    len = str.length();
    map<string,int>m;
    while(i<len)
    {
        temp = str[0];
        while(j<len-1)
        {
            str[j] = str[j+1];
            j++;
        }
        str[j] = temp;
        m[str] = k;
        k++;
        i++;j=0;
    }
    str = m.rbegin()->first;
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here the index with greater value is selected,
//if the same char occurs again the next characters
// of prev and curr characters is checked:-Prev=maxIndex,curr=i    
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int getIndex(char *str){
int max=INT_MIN,maxIndex;
int n=strlen(str);
int j,p;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(str[i]>max)
    {
        max=str[i];
        maxIndex=i;
    }
    else if(str[i]==max)
    {
        j=maxIndex+1;
        p=(i+1)%n;
        while(j<n && p<n && str[j]==str[p]){
         j++;
         p=(p+1)%n;
        }
        maxIndex=str[p]>str[j]?i:maxIndex;
    }
}
return maxIndex;
}
int main(void)
{
char str[4000008];
scanf("%s",str);
int i=getIndex(str);
for(int j=i;j<strlen(str);j++)
cout<<str[j];
for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
cout<<str[j];



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm, corrected, comes down to:

1. Set current best rotation to identity (start of rotated string is current index 0).
2. For each possible rotation (all other starting indices):

   1. Compare to current-best-rotation with something like `wrapcmp` below.
   2. Set the current-best-rotation if we had a better candidate.

Time-Complexity: O(n*n)
Space-Complexity: in-place

```
// Function to do ordinal-comparison on two rotations of a buffer
// buffer: The buffer containing the string
// n: The buffers size (string-length)
// a: Index where the first buffer starts pre-rotation
// b: Index where the second buffer starts pre-rotation
int wrapcmp(const void* buffer, size_t n, size_t a, size_t b) {
    auto x = (const unsigned char*)buffer;
    auto m = n - std::max(a, b);
    int ret = memcmp(x+a, x+b, m);
    if(ret) return ret;
    auto left = n - m;
    a = (a + m) % n;
    b = (b + m) % n;
    m = left - std::max(a, b);
    ret = memcmp(x+a, x+b, m);
    if(ret) return ret;
    a = (a + m) % n;
    b = (b + m) % n;
    return memcmp(x+a, x+b, left - m);
}
```

Used on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b138a6394483447
Putting it into the general algo left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: i am not comparing two different strings...I am checking the lexicographically largest possible string formed by the rotation of the given string..

Comment: @codefreak: Ehm... Where do I speak about a second string? I just added a utility-function to compare those rotated strings...

Comment: ohh okay...can you please explain what a and b actually represent And why are only the first and the second rotations considered in the function? if possible can u please explain with the help of an working example..Thankyou.

Comment: Rephrased inputs to utility-function. I do not consider the first and second rotations in that functions, but I compare two specified rotations. The function is only a building-block you need for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was too tempting so I may as well post my effort. Not sure how it rates efficiency wize. It seems to work as far as I tested it:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::string max_rot(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string tmp;
    std::string max;

    std::string::const_iterator m = std::max_element(s.begin(), s.end());
    if(m != s.end())
        for(char c = *m; (m = std::find(m, s.end(), c)) != s.end(); ++m)
            if(max < tmp.assign(m, s.end()).append(s.begin(), m))
                max = tmp;

    return max;
}


int main()
{
    size_t times = 0;
    std::string text;

    do { std::cout << "\nHow many words? : "; }
    while(std::getline(std::cin, text) && !(std::istringstream(text) >> times));

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    while(times-- && (std::cin >> text))
        words.push_back(text);

    for(const auto& s: words)
        std::cout << max_rot(s) << '\n';

}
```

By way of explanation. It finds the highest character value in the string and rotates the string to make that character first. If then looks for duplicate highest characters in the remainder of the string keeping track of the highest attempt. There maybe room for optimization.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes, this algorithm is O(N^2). It is efficient with regards to the first character, but after that it is basically brute force. The ''tmp.assign'' call is O(N), and typically you will have to call it N/26 times.
To make the algorithm efficient, you have to apply the logic of the first character all the way through, see my solution (though I'm nowhere near as elegant a user of the STL as you, very nice).

Answer (score 0):

This challenge is used in an active contest, I request no answer to be provided till 18th Sep 9 PM IST. Because the code is visible, we might have to ban the user from participating in any of our contests going forward.